# Change colors in Primefaces chart

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to implement Primefaces chart from this [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/barChart.jsf).

I managed to create this example:

```
<div id="datachart" style="margin: 0 auto; width:850px; height:400px; position:relative">
    <h:form prependId="false">  
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  

        <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{bean.categoryModel}"   
                    title="Accounts and Groups" min="0" max="#{DashboardController.chartMaxSize}" style="height:400px"
                    shadow="true" barMargin="40" barPadding="90" seriesColors="4D94FF, 1975FF" 
                    yaxisLabel="Size" zoom="true"> 
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.itemSelect}" update="growl" />
        </p:barChart>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

I created this css in order to change the chart color labels:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .jqplot-title{
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    .jqplot-xaxis-label{
        color:#FFFFFF; 
    }
    .jqplot-yaxis-label{
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    .jqplot-xaxis-tick{
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    jqplot-yaxis-tick{
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
```

But for some reason the color is not changed. Can you help me to find what I'm missing?

Comment: My tip for you is open your app in Chrome (or Firefox, just giving my example as I would approach this), and right click your chart. Choose inspect element (or just hit F12). On the right part of the inspector you can view the styles applied, and whether your css is actually being used, or (what easily happens while using Primefaces) whether your css gets overridden by higher prioritised styleclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `<f:facet name="last">`

```
<f:facet name="last">
    your css styles goes here
    Or even better drop them into .css file and include it here
</f:facet>
```

for further reference take a look at this

[Customizable Resource Ordering](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1433)

And

[Resource Ordering In PrimeFaces](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/resource-ordering-in-primefaces/)

Comment: I found the problem - the colors of the labels are defined into charts.js